# PostreSQL pg_archivecleanup on tar.gz

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, wal

I want to cleanup my wal folder.
In documentation pg_archivecleanup require path to last backup file with extension: **.backup**.

My all backups are in **tar.gz.** When I extract tar.gz I don't see any file with backup extension.
Not sure how to do pg_archivecleanup with tar.gz?

Comment: Online backups generated `.backup` files into the WAL stream, not in the backup itself.  How are you taking this backup?  (No, telling us the extension doesn't tell us that, lots of things end in tar.gz)

Comment: @jjanes I have setup wal archiving in one folder and run pg_basebackup in another folder with options tar.gz. When I extract from tar.gz there is no .backup extension.

Comment: The `.backup` file will be in the WAL archive, not the base backup.  If there is more than one of those, the base backup itself should contain a file named 'backup_label' and inside that it should indicate what the corresponding `.backup` file would be.

Comment: @jjanes So when I do pg_archivecleanup I should point to latest .backup file inside wal archive folder right?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have made sure the latest backup is valid and has been copied offsite, or whatever your policy is.  But really pg_archivecleanup is archaic, why not just use replication slots?

Comment: @jjanes I am no expert in PostreSql administration so I created wal archives and using full db backups as my recover strategies. Setting up replications would be much more complicated for me and require additional server.